# info window in origin and destination marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I have two markers in map for source and destination. I have implement geo code API to extract locality and postal code.I done with that.I have info window to display that.when i click origin it display that response and same for destination.I have done this up to the level but one issues are there.when I execute the origin URL it shows the response correctly. when I click the end marker it execute destination URL.But the info content view gets override and content of origin markers also changed.I want to fix this.suggest some solutions..

```
btnFindPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendRequest();


        }
    });




private void sendRequest() {
    String origin = etOrigin.getText().toString();

    String destination = etDestination.getText().toString();
    url= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+etOrigin.getText()+"AIzaSyDnwLF2-WfK8cVZt9OoDYJ9Y8kspXhEHfI";

    if (origin.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter origin address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if (destination.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter destination address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    try {

        new DirectionFinder(this, origin, destination).execute();
        new GetLocationTask().execute();
    }   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    void getrequest(){
        url= "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+etDestination.getText()+"AIzaSyDnwLF2-WfK8cVZt9OoDYJ9Y8kspXhEHfI";
        new GetLocationTask().execute();

    }





googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {



        // Use default InfoWindow frame

        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {



            return null;
        }

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow

        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {


            // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);


           TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);


            String ll="";
            HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            TextView type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);
                for (int z=0;z<list1.size();z++) {
                    hm = list1.get(z);
                    ll = ll + hm.get("long_name");

                }




            // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
            return v;

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: any body have answer